# How to display only unique values by using listagg in oracle12c

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

These are Tables I have to use while displaying the data

```
table1
-----------------------------------------------------
col1                col2        id
1223                ram         254
1232                rajesh      345


table 2
--------------------------------------
id              col5        col6        col7     col8
254             1223-1      8789        abc      67
254             1223-2      8790        efg      87
254             1223-3      8791        bcd      67
254             1223-4      8792        abc      87
345             1232-1      7897        cdf      89
345             1232-2      7898        cdf      60
```

and query we used to join the tables

```
select 
        t1.col1,
        listagg(t2.col5,',') within group(order by t2.col6)as col5,
        listagg(t2.col7,',') within group(order by t2.col6)as col7,
          listagg(t2.col8,',') within group(order by t2.col6)as col8
     from 
            table1 t1
            join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id;
        group by col1
```

Output while using above query

```
 col1            col5                      col7    col8
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1233        1223-1,1223-2,1223-3,1223-4     abc,efg,bcd,abc     67,87,67,87
 1232       1232-1,1232-2                   cdf,cdf                89,60
```

Expected result:

```
 col1            col5                      col7       col8
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1233       1223-1,1223-2,1223-3,1223-4     abc,efg,bcd   67,87
 1232       1232-1,1232-2                   cdf           89,60
```

We are not supposed to use Wm_concat as it is undocumented . Col5,col7 and Col8 should be ordered by col6 only.

Comment: Do you have to use `listagg`?  I don't believe that can eliminate duplicates.  I'd write a custom user-defined aggregate function myself.  You could probably write multiple joins to get the distinct values and then use `listagg` but that won't be as efficient.  Doing an `order by col6` when you're eliminating duplicate `col5`, `col7`, and `col8` values can also be confusing-- do you want to sort by the `min(col6)`, the `max(col6)`, or something else? After eliminating duplicates, one `col5` value may correspond to many different `col6` values.

Comment: No, I can use any funtion to display the output but the list or string  should be in order of col6.

Comment: As I said, "in order of col6" doesn't make sense when you're aggregating rows.  Let's say that the two `abc` values from `col7` were on rows where `col6` was 1 and 100.  The row with a `col7` value of `efg` had a `col6` value of 50.  Should `abc` come before `efg` because 1 < 50?  Or should `abc` come after `efg` because 50 < 100?

Comment: If col7 have 2,4,2,5,3,7 ,4 after Listagg which is ordered by  col6 . on the list we have to do  an operation so  the result will be  2,4,5,3,7  ,avoiding next reapeating duplicate value.

Comment: So sort by `min(col6)` then?

Comment: I am able to sort them , i need to get unique values thats where i am struck.

Comment: You can sort them.  But you need to help us understand how to sort them in order to write the query.  I believe that your last update indicates that you want to sort the distinct values by the `min(col6)` value associated with the value.  Is that what you are saying?  Or am I misunderstanding your desired sort algorithm?

Comment: I think i have confused you .I wanted to conacte all the values in col7 and col 8 by grouping with col1 values . so there will be two rows in result.Now its about data in a cells in col7 and col8,  where there are repeated values. Main aim is to eliminate repeating value in the cell. I think i made it clear.

Comment: You've said that you want to order your results by `col6`.  In your data, the `col7` value "abc" occurs twice, once where `col6=8789` and once where `col6=8792`.  Which of the two values should be used to determine the sort order?  I believe that you want to use the `min(col6)` value.  But I've asked a few times now and I'm not seeing a definitive answer.  If you want to use some other rule to order the data, you're going to need to help us by spelling out that rule.

Comment: you are right Yeh i want to use min(col6)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which returns the first distinct occurrence of the requested column when ordered by col6.  It uses an intermediate step to first eliminate the duplicates, then does the final listagg:

```
with t3 as (
SELECT T1.COL1
     , T2.COL6
     , case row_number() over (partition by t1.col1, t2.col5 order by t1.col1)
           when 1 then t2.col5  -- Output the first occurrance of Col5
           else null
       end COL5
     , case row_number() over (partition by t1.col1, t2.col7 order by t1.col1)
           when 1 then t2.col7  -- Output the first occurrance of Col7
           else null
       end COL7
     , case row_number() over (partition by t1.col1, t2.col8 order by t1.col1)
           when 1 then t2.col8  -- Output the first occurrance of Col8
           else null
       end COL8
  FROM TABLE1 T1
  JOIN TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
)
 select t3.col1
      , listagg(COL5,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T3.COL6) COL5
      , listagg(COL7,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T3.COL6) COL7
      , listagg(COL8,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T3.COL6) COL8
   from t3
  group by col1;
```

Results:

```
COL1    COL5                        COL7        COL8
------- --------------------------- ----------- -----
1223    1223-1,1223-2,1223-3,1223-4 ABC,EFG,BCD 67,87
1232    1232-1,1232-2               CDF         89,60
```